# How can I add quantity option for product page in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, customization, storefront

I'm using WooCommerce 2.6.14 and Storefront theme. I want to add quantity field in product page like [this page](http://plugins.themes.zone/product/ninja-silhouette/). I've tried many plugins but it's not working!

Comment: Woocommerce gives quantity field by default on product page.

Comment: Yes like @VidishPurohit said it is by default there.. However if you have marked your product to be Sold individually, could it be the case? in Product settings-> Inventory -> Checkbox ( Enable this to only allow one of this item to be bought in a single order), make sure it is UnChecked...